# Raspberry video stream outside local network

Tags: python, flask, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3, opencv

I have my Raspberry Pi 3B streaming video to my local network.

My problem is: I want to access the stream from anywhere, and right now I can only watch it from a browser if I'm connected to the same network.

Here's the code I'm using.

```py
class Streamer:
   app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../resources/templates')
    stream = None

    @staticmethod
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('streaming.html')

    @staticmethod
    def gen():
        while True:
            frame = Camara.get_frame()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

    @staticmethod
    @app.route('/video_feed')
    def video_feed():
        return Response(Streamer.gen(),
                        mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

    @staticmethod
    def start():
        Camara.set_stream()
        Streamer.stream = Process(target=Streamer.app.run, args=('0.0.0.0', 5000))
        Streamer.stream.start()

    @staticmethod
    def shutdown():
        if Streamer.stream:
            Streamer.stream.terminate()
            Streamer.stream.join()
            Streamer.stream = None
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The Camera class

```py
class Camara:
    cap = None
    out = None

    @staticmethod
    def set_stream():
        try:
            if Camara.cap:
                logging.debug("Camera busy")
                Camara.cap.release()
            Camara.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        except Exception as exception:
            logging.error("Error setting up camera: " + exception)

    @staticmethod
    def get_frame():
        ret1, frame = Camara.cap.read()
        ret2, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

The html template

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>YoloDoor Stream</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="bg" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What hostname/IP are you trying to view the stream on from outside your local network?  It sounds like you may need to expose the IP of your Pi publicly

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bunnmatt.. If you are outside of your network, then you would need to add this to your firewall.

On your local network, if you go to http://192.168.1.1, that should take you to the admin page of your router. From there you can setup a rule to expose this app/port to the outside world. 
Then to access it you would type in your house's IP into a browser, and access it that way.

Another way (incase you can't access your routers Admin page) is to use Ngrok: https://ngrok.com/, this handles the proxy stuff, and will expose it via http or https..

A word of warning.. Exposing ports outside of your network opens you up for attack. Definitely do a bit more googling before you start changing a lot of settings in your router.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If information such as `router model`, `server (Apache/NginX/Node)` you will receive much accurate information. The information gathered is only RPi3 and implementation language (not relevant for this question).

As others pointed, solution you are looking for is **exposing your local port to public**.

Assuming your stream is accessible at `http://192.168.0.1:8080` on your local network. You need to config your router for Port Forwarding/Virtual Server.

You goal will be to..

- Assign static IP and determine the port number to port forward
- Added basic auth to the root directory ([read on Apache Basic Auth](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) to add basic login prompt)
- Expose the IP (and port number if different than `port 80`) to public via DNS

> Solution below is via noip.com (DNS provider) - free version require confirmation every 30 days.

1. Create [no-ip.com](https://www.noip.com/) account to own a hostname (eg: mycam.ddns.net)
2. Setup [no-ip DUC (Dynamic Update Client)](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/install-ip-duc-onto-raspberry-pi/) so your hostname will tally with your local network IP.
3. Successful setup will allow the example scenario to work by accessing `mycam.ddns.net:8080`
4. Done

#### Is DNS required?

Your local network IP to outside world (produced by your router) changes intermittently. DNS allows weird number such as `175.143.141.29` today and differently tomorrow to be used like a domain (eg: `mycam.ddns.net`)

#### Is local static IP required?

When your DHCP is renewed (router restarted, different device logging off and on), your IP used by your RPi today (eg: `192.168.0.1`) might be `192.168.0.9` on next renewal.

Static IP allows `192.168.0.1` to be reserved to a `device MAC address (another form of network identity)` so it always pointing to the same device on future renewal.

Although newer router is much smarter to reserve such IP for such device for longer period. However no-ip DUC might does this for you as it tells the server which IP its currently connected from.

#### Security

If you can access it publicly, others will be able to do the same. Proceed with common sense.

#### Alternative setup

Due to various setup possibilities, read more on Port Forwarding/Virtual Server.
Example of more RPi setup here: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-port-forwarding/